# Check if value is equal to another value

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

**What i am after:**

I am developing a discord.js (V14) bot at the moment. The idea is the following. If a member executes the following / command:

`/mute target:@member time:1d reason:spamming`

Check if `target:@member` is equal to the bot it self.

**My issue:**

The below code should in theory (to my knownledge) be enough to check if the `target:@member` is equal to `discord bot`. However, my code completely skips that step. Even if i verify via `console.log` that both values are equal.

**The Code:**

10258xxxx - `console.log(user.id);`

10258xxxx - `console.log(interaction.guild.members.me.id);`

```js
module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName("mute")
        .setDescription("Mute a member.")
        .addUserOption(option =>
            option.setName("target")
                .setDescription("Select the user you wish to mute.")
        )
        .addStringOption(option =>
            option.setName("time")
                .setDescription("How long should the mute last?")
        )
        .addStringOption(option =>
            option.setName("reason")
                .setDescription("What is the reason of the mute?")
        ),

    async execute(interaction) {
        const user = options.getUser("target");

        if (user.id === interaction.guild.members.me.id){
            return interaction.reply("I can't mute my self.");
        }

        return interaction.reply("Success");
    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not completely familiar with discord, but it looks like you might need to add the `await` keyword

```
return await interaction.reply("I can't mute my self.");
```

Without going into detail of how async await works, what you could test is the following to see that the line is running:

```
if (user.id === interaction.guild.members.me.id){
    console.log("Can you see me?");
    return interaction.reply("I can't mute my self.");
}
```

If you can see the log, what is happening is the code stops running before waiting for the async function to finish. If you want to understand this better, learn more about async await!

Comment: await after 'return' is unnecessary as an async function's return statement returns a promise by default. That's why you don't need to use await after the 'return' keyword.

Comment: Thank you so much Alan, this worked for me <3 I am a step closer to my goal now :) `return await interaction.reply("");` worked. no more errors.

Comment: @Arman that might be true, if the function that calls `execute` call it with `await`, but I think it is a discord function that is outside a coders control. If you look at the docs, it expects await https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/general/welcome. If you are saying that return is unnecessary, that seems true in this case, but not always

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should use `interaction.options.getUser()`.

```js
const user = interaction.options.getUser('target')

if(user.id == interaction.guild.members.me.id) return await interaction.reply('I can\'t mute myself');

await interaction.reply('Success!'); // don't use return here
```

Comment: @Alan Schapira's answer worked <3 thank you.